# Merging list of lists into single list

Tags: prolog

Please follow the input/output requirements:

```
Input:    
[[h,i],[h,e,l,l,o],[l,a,p,t,o,p]]
```

Simply I need to get rid of those `,`:

```
Expected output: 
[hi, hello, laptop].
```

My code:

```
make_LoL([],Res).
make_LoL([H|T],Res) :-  
    atom_con(H,Out),
    newRes = [Out|Res], 
    make_LoL(T,newRes).

atom_con([],Out).
atom_con([H1,H2,H3|T],Out) :-
    atom_concat(H1,H2,Ou),
    atom_concat(Ou,H3,Out),
    atom_con([], Out).
```

When I run it, it loops forever. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Short answer: `maplist(atom_chars,As, [[h,i],[h,e,l,l,o],[l,a,p,t,o,p]]).`

Comment: ... and no, I cannot observe a looping - rather a failure in your code

Comment: @false Cool, thanks.

Comment: @false I'm curious, how can I add dash between two chars, e.g. `[[h-i,h-e-l-l-o],[l-a-p-t-o-p]]` ?

Comment: Where did you get that rep from? I rather suspect you meant `nil-h-i` etc

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
string([], []).
string([H | T], [S | Z]) :- helper(H, S), string(T, Z).

helper([A], A).
helper([H | T], S) :- helper(T, Z), atom_concat(H, -, Z1), atom_concat(Z1, Z, S).
```

If a sublist is empty, pattern matching will fail and result will be false. Thus, this solution only woks when each sublist contains at least one character.